# Listing between two alphabet letter (From a to z)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make a function for listing. If user enter the letter 'a' it will list just whatever starts with 'a' inside of `%MINDEX%`.

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=[]()" %%a in ('findstr /i /r /b /c:"!LST-GLN[1]!" %MINDEX%') do (
  set /a SIRA+=1
  set FISIM[!SIRA!]=%%a
  set FYIL[!SIRA!]=%%b
  set FIDD[!SIRA!]=%%c
)

for /l %%i in (1,1,!SIRA!) do call :_Yazdir "%%i" "!FISIM[%%i]!" "!FYIL[%%i]!" "!FIDD[%%i]!" "!SATIRRENGI!"
```

Lets say we have a second variable (`!LST-GLN[2]!`) how can i list between those variables?
I mean from `!LST-GLN[1]!` to `!LST-GLN[2]!` for example `f` to `i` Something like;

```
for /l %%a in (f,1,i) do ..
```

Is it possible ? if so how can we do ?

PS.1 Case sensitivity is not important.

PS.2 if we can add 0-9 to alphabet (before the 'a') that will be great but it is not important either.

Eg. of `%MINDEX%`

```
asd(1234)[12345]
bsd(1234)[12345]
bse(1234)[12345]
csd(1234)[12345]
.
.
.
```

Comment: As far as i know you have to use number for `for /l` loops and letters doesnt count as a start/end value for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method process the subrange of letters desired. Just adjust it to suit your needs:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set letters=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

set start=f
set end=i

set "temp=!letters:*%start%=%start%!"
for /F "delims=$" %%a in ("!temp:%end%=%end%$!") do for %%b in (%%a) do echo %%b
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. I mean why there is a `$` as a delim ? Or why `temp` contains `*`

Comment: @JohnDOE `*`Includes everything before. And if `$` is a deliminator than everything before the end character will be included.

Comment: But then why not just `"delims="`, which means there are no delimiters and to treat the whole line as one string?